# Setting specific column width in Jaspersoft Studio

Tags: jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

I am developing a report using Jaspersoft Studio. In the report some columns require only 3 Numbers (Unicode) and some columns 8 Numbers (Unicode).

I am trying to make the Column bigger in width which require long numbers so that it fits in one line and another one smaller in width that require short numbers (Only 3 numbers).

In Studio I tried to do with mouse draging but it automatically resize all other columns which is making it harder to fix the size for specific columns.

Any easier way to do this?

Here is the screenshot of JasperViewer:
[image: wer]
<sub>(source: [toile-libre.org](http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1464120456.png))</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a `Table` you can set the desired width directly in the `Column`, not in the cell or the cell component. I tried it and if I enter a number like `40 px` directly into the `Width` field, everything seems to work out.

Comment: I need to it in Advance>>Column Properties ?

Comment: Why use the advanced settings? Select the Cell in `Outline`. Then `Properties / Cell / Cell Width`.

Comment: could you show us an example?

I have <jr:column width="150"> and still when the report is generated the size is not that one